# Proguard doesn't look into embedded jars for reference lookup

Tags: java, osgi, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate a bundle with proguard. Because of project specific reasons, my bundles have library jars in them, such as:

```
bundle.jar
   |
   |-META-INF
   |
   |-library.jar
   |
   \-org (and the rest of my source tree)
```

The Manifest.mf file in META-INF includes the line:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,library.jar
```

And this is all auto-generated and good.

Now, the problem comes when proguard tries to obfuscate methods from library.jar (let's say I have a good reason to do that). In those cases, it won't find library.jar since it's not part of the dependent libraries, and proguard seemingly ignores the Bundle-Classpath entry in the manifest file.

So, the question is: can that be done at all? Or is proguard completely osgi agnostic and can't handle those tags at all? Is there a way I can provide an in-jar dependency to proguard?

Thanks!

Comment: For the record: I haven't solved this in a satisfactory way (yet). What I'm doing so far is using dependency:unpack-dependencies to unpack the subjars inside the jar...

Comment: @NeilBartlett 's solution is the strictily correct one, and Eric Lafortune 's limits the possible solutions.I have ended up opting for unpacking the jar inside my target jar, since it doesn't really make a difference for me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not assemble the bundle with its embedded JAR *after* obfuscating with Proguard, rather than before?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to obfuscate at the jar level. I have a bunch of different bundles with interdependencies...

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can't obfuscate `library.jar` before putting it into `bundle.jar`....

Comment: I see! Ok, you are right, that is indeed doable. Not the simplest to setup, though. I've finally opted for unpacking the classes of the jar inside my parent jar, and obfuscating the lot in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ProGuard is completely OSGi agnostic. It is independent of any platform, on purpose.

Furthermore, ProGuard handles class files, optionally inside jars, optionally inside wars, optionally inside ears, optionally inside zips, but not class files inside jars inside jars.

Cfr. the ProGuard manual > Usage > Class paths.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies things!

Answer (score 1):

If you use bnd (maven, bndtools, etc) you can *unroll* a jar file. Use the following instruction:

```
 Include-Resource: @library.jar
```

In that case you get a normal JAR that can also be used on the class path. This should provide no problem for obfuscators. If you want to export packages from this library, use -exportcontents instead of Export-Package, they both have the same syntax.